# Pyechonest - Trouble finding module

Tags: python-3.x, echonest

I'm using the echonest python package.  It works find on my ubuntu linux laptop using Anaconda python 2.7.
https://github.com/echonest/pyechonest

However, when I use my windows 10 laptop with Anaconda 3.4 I cannot run any code because it cannot find the util module when I import artist.  I can do this fine on linux python 2.7

Windows 10 Anaconda 3.4 dist

Run:
from pyechonest import artist

Error:
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyechonest-9.0.0-py3.4.egg\pyechonest\artist.py", line 11, in 
    import util

ImportError: No module named 'util'

I'm a fairly new to python so forgive me I missed anything obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem - it's because the version of pyechonest currently available on pypi isn't compatible with Python 3.  See https://github.com/echonest/pyechonest/pull/37

Until it gets merged you can install the branch from jsbronder's repository like so:

`pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/jsbronder/pyechonest.git@py3`